# Consistency test

Tags: reliability, ranks

I have data that consists of 7 characteristics for each participant. There are about 170 participants. The test was repeated in some time and the same 7 characteristics were acquired. I need to find out if the overall profile remained to be the same. The positions of the leading characteristics. For example, if the 3 leading characteristics stayed on the top in the retest data. Even if second become third or third become second.

What test should I use to find this type of consistency?

Comment: How is the position of one of these characteristics determined for a given participant?  What kinds of variables are these characteristics (what kind of data do they represent: nominal, interval, etc.)?

Comment: Also, how is "leading" calculated and compared?  Are you comparing one individual's top 3 characteristics with the same individual's top 3 in the two periods, regardless of whether those top characteristics are the same for different individuals?  Or are you computing leading characteristics across the entire set of individuals after the first test, and then want to see if those same 3 characteristics remained at the top in the second test?